# Moving the image in canvas in user defined path

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-animation

I need to move the image in the canvas. The image should not follow a linear or circle or elliptical path. I know this can be achieved by using the COS and SIN functions. But here I need to get the image traversed in a 4 different path like I have shown in the below snapshot. Please help me if there is anyway to achieve this. It should be fine even If I get any idea to achieve this .

snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try the android animation package first - you should be able to define a few points and get this to smooth the path between the points.
See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Comment: This may be the idea. I can take this if I do not find any other option.. can you help me with an example

Comment: Sure thing. There's a tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html

Comment: ...and a simple example here: http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/implement-slide-in-and-slide-out.html?m=1